# How to get network-parameter file via network bootstrapper for VMs with the same ports

Tags: corda

Currently, I have nodes on different machines/VMs with different IPs. Hence they may also share the same ports but different IPs i.e h2port.

I am consolidating all the vms' node.config (with their own IP address and legal identities) in a folder and running the network bootstrapper. I am getting an error `port is being used`, so I assume the bootstrapper will concurrently stand up the nodes which will cause the conflict in ports.

I can still get the nodes to individually generate their `nodeInfos..` file and manually distributing them without the bootstrapper. It is the network-parameter file that I'm having trouble trying to workaround.

Notary example node.config.

```
basedir="/opt/corda"
myLegalName="O=Notary, L=London, C=UK"
notary {
    validating=false
}
p2pAddress="X.X.X.X:10002"
rpcUsers=[]
```

Normal node node.config

```
basedir : "/opt/corda"
p2pAddress : "X.X.X.X:10002"
rpcSettings {
    address="localhost:10003"
    adminAddress="localhost:10014"
    useSsl = false
    standAloneBroken = false
}
h2port : 11000
myLegalName : "O=Company1, OU=Company, L=London, C=UK"
extraAdvertisedServiceIds: [ "" ]
useHTTPS : false
devMode : true
rpcUsers=[
    {
        user=corda
        password=password
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
    }
]
sshd {
  port=2222
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question to show each node's `node.conf` file please?

Comment: Edited question with node.conf example. Also, does it makes sense to consolidate all the vms' node.conf in one folder to bootstrap before distributing it back to all the remote vms? What I observe is that the bootstrapper will generate new certs for each nodes before generating their nodeInfo and network-parameter. So does that mean the key used to generate SignedNodeInfo is different than the ones already on the vms?

Comment: Hey, can you open that as a separate question? I cannot replicate your issue. Can you replicate it with just the notary and one node's conf, or do you need to have more node.confs in the folder?

Comment: I think if you only had 1 notary and 1 normal node, it wont hit the error, since only 1 node is explicitly specifying the h2port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause**: Putting `notary_node.conf`, `company1_node.conf`, `company2_node.conf` in the same dir. Both `company1` and `company2` are from different IPs but had the same `h2port`. Trying to use `network-bootstrapper` will concurrently stand up the nodes which will cause a port conflict.

**Solution**: `node.conf` from other nodes are **not** mandatory in generating network-parameter since `NetworkParameters` only consists of information about notary's `nodeInfo`, minimum platform, etc.

By only having `notary_node.config` as the sole config in the directory and running `network-bootstrapper`, it will succeed in generating the network-parameters file. Although by doing this, you won't be able to leverage on the bootstrapper to automatically generate `nodeInfo-...` files for all the other nodes' quickly, but you can manually use the `--just-generate-node-info` on each of the nodes, and collect their `nodeInfo-..` files.

Then you can proceed to manually distribute the `network-parameters` and `nodeInfo-..` files to all the other nodes.